# How to write a "numpy.float64" value (object) in the file at the beginning on first line?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was trying to write a "numpy.float64" object stored in a variable "mean" to existing file at the beginning.

```
   mean = 45  # has datatype = numpy.float64

   with open (filename, 'rw') as new:
      lines = new.readlines() # read old content
       new.seek(0) # go back to the beginning of the file
       new.write((mean.item())) # write new content at the beginning
       for line in lines: # write old content after new
            new.write(line)
       new.close()
```

And getting following error:

```
    TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Anybody have a good suggestions for this?

I referred similar answer from StackOverflow but datatype used there was string.

Answer (score 0):

use 'wb':

```
with open (filename, 'wb') as new:
    new.write(mean)
```

then for reading back:

```
with open (filename, 'rb') as new:
    val_b = new.read()
    val = np.frombuffer(val_b, dtype=np.float64)
    print(val)
```

Comment: It write's binary file. I just want to write 'mean' value at the beginning of the file and rest file need to be as it is. This code seems to erase earlier data and converting to binary file.